# In protractor how to click on column based on other column value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I need to click on button in a row based on other associated value for that button in same row .
Need to click on : 
   **button ng-if="ctrl.showEdit"**
based on text contain 'abc' in following td or class 
    **class="width-25 ng-binding"**
Both above attributes are in a same row

[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fMCF.jpg)

```
this.EditByName = function (input) {
        element.all(by.className('table pagination-table-margin ng-scope ng-table')).then(function (rows) {
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                row.all(by.className('ng-binding')).then(function (columns) {
                     element.all(by.cssContainingText(input)).then(function () {
                        element(by.className('btn-grid ng-scope')).click();
                        console.log(input);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XPATHs selectors, so you can backtrack once you have found the columns with the value you want to use as reference, like this:

```
element(by.cssContainingText("td", "abc"))
  .element(by.xpath("..")) // This selects the parent <tr>
  .all(by.css("button[ng-if='ctr.showEdit']"))
```